# Enabling Passpoint feature in AOSP

Tags: android, wifi, android-source, android-wifi, hotspot

I am working on an AOSP customization project where i want to enable the ***Hotspot 2.0/Passpoint*** feature through my code. From the Android developers site, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-passpoint I got to know that requirements for supporting Passpoint are included in AOSP, we have to enable it by modifying the ***device.mk*** file. It also says *"To support Passpoint, implement the Wi-Fi HAL and enable the feature flag for Passpoint"*. This part i didn't get.
I have also enabled the flag ***'hs20'*** in ***external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf*** file but that was of no help.

I want to see the UI in Wifi Settings preferences for enabling and disabling Passpoint as given in the figure below.

[image: Passpoint]

Is the switch available by default in AOSP or are we supposed to add it?
I thought this will be hidden and will be enabled by enabling the feature flag mentioned in the link above. But i didnt find any code for that preferences in the ***wifi_configure_settings.xml***

If anyone have worked on Passpoint, please help me with this.

Please let me know if any more details are required.